# Shared memory n-body simulation in Chapel

Tags: parallel-processing, chapel

I'm trying to re-implement the shared memory implementation of the n-body simulation presented in chapter 6.1.6 in An Introduction to Parallel Programming by Peter Pacheco. In that chapter it was implemented using OpenMP.

Here is my parallel implementation using [OpenMP](https://github.com/novoselrok/parallel-algorithms/blob/a053168851408c1a5f486877b927f9f2337b38a8/nbody/openmp/main.c). And here is a serial implementation using [Chapel](https://github.com/novoselrok/parallel-algorithms/blob/a053168851408c1a5f486877b927f9f2337b38a8/nbody/chapel/main.chpl). I'm having issues implementing a shared memory parallel implementation using Chapel. Since there is no way to get the rank of a thread in a `forall` loop, I can't use the same approach as in the OpenMP implementation. I would have to use the `coforall` loop, create the tasks and distribute the iterations manually. That does not seem practical and suggests that there is a more elegant way to solve this within Chapel.

I'm looking for guidance and suggestions on how to better solve this problem using the tools provided by Chapel.

Comment: Would you be able to make a sample input data file available?  I'm not having any luck generating one using your gen.py script (possibly due to personal shortcomings).

Comment: Sure, I added some example files here: https://github.com/novoselrok/parallel-algorithms/tree/master/nbody/data. I also updated gen.py script with instruction on how to run it.

Comment: Great, thanks!  One other belated thought:  Since your links above are pointing to the master branch of a GitHub repository, you may want to either inline a snapshot of the code to this question to make it timeless as the GitHub repo evolves; or to point to a specific branch/SHA within the GitHub repo to make it continue to refer to the same version of code (assuming the whole repo doesn't go away).

Comment: Good point! I edited the original post with links to the commit, but I can't edit the previous comment, so I am adding the link to the data here: https://github.com/novoselrok/parallel-algorithms/tree/a053168851408c1a5f486877b927f9f2337b38a8/nbody/data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a (+) [reduce intent](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/technotes/reduceIntents.html) on `forces` in your forall-loop, which will give each task its own private copy of `forces` and then (sum) reduce their individual copies back into the original `forces` variable as the tasks complete.  This would be done by attaching the following with-clause to your forall loop:

```
  forall q in 0..#n_bodies with (+ reduce forces) {
```

While here, I looked for other ways to make the code a bit more elegant and would suggest changing from a 2D array to an array-of-arrays for this problem in order to collapse a bunch of trios of similar code statements for x, y, z components down to a single statement.  I also made use of your `pDomain` variable and created a type alias for `[0..#3] real` in order to remove some redundancy in the code.  Oh, and I removed the `use`s of the `Math` and `IO` modules because they are auto-used in Chapel programs.

Here's where that left me:

```
config const filename = "input.txt";
config const iterations = 100;
config const out_filename = "out.txt";
const X = 0;
const Y = 1;
const Z = 2;
const G = 6.67e-11;
config const dt = 0.1;

// Read input file, initialize bodies                                       
var f = open(filename, iomode.r);
var reader = f.reader();

var n_bodies = reader.read(int);
const pDomain = {0..#n_bodies};

type vec3 = [0..#3] real;

var forces: [pDomain] vec3;
var velocities: [pDomain] vec3;
var positions: [pDomain] vec3;
var masses: [pDomain] real;

for i in pDomain {
  positions[i] = reader.read(vec3);

  velocities[i] = reader.read(vec3);

  masses[i] = reader.read(real);
}

f.close();
reader.close();

for i in 0..#iterations {
  // Reset forces                                                           
  forces = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0];

  forall q in pDomain with (+ reduce forces) {
    for k in pDomain {
      if k <= q {
        continue;
      }
      var diff = positions[q] - positions[k];
      var dist = sqrt(diff[X]**2 + diff[Y]**2 + diff[Z]**2);
      var dist_cubed = dist**3;

      var tmp = -G * masses[q] * masses[k] / dist_cubed;
      var force_qk = tmp * diff;

      forces[q] += force_qk;
      forces[k] -= force_qk;
    }
  }


  forall q in pDomain {
    positions[q] += dt * velocities[q];
    velocities[q] += dt / masses[q] * forces[q];
  }
}

var outf = open(out_filename, iomode.cw);
var writer = outf.writer();

for q in pDomain {
  writer.writeln("%er %er %er %er %er %er".format(positions[q][X], positions[q][Y], positions[q][Z], velocities[q][X], velocities[q][Y], velocities[q][Z]));
}

writer.close();
outf.close();
```

One other change you could consider making would be to replace the forall-loop that updates positions and velocities with the following whole-array statements:

```
    positions += dt * velocities;                                           
    velocities += dt / masses * forces;
```

where the main tradeoff would be that the forall would implement the statements in a fused manner using a single parallel loop while the whole-array statements would not (at least in the current version 1.18 version of the compiler).